# grok pattern is not working in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have the "*01 Jul 2014 [accType] name -  >20 cc = 100*" (P.S: there are two space before '>20') in log file and the config file has,

```
..input..
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", [
              " -  >20 cc = %{NUMBER:value:int}"
    ]]
 }
}
..output...
```

the pattern matches when I try in https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ but not working when I run this config with actual logstash. other patterns in the same config file are working except this one pattern.

Comment: That grok works in a small test harness in 1.4.2 and 1.5.2.

Comment: lemme check my logstash version

Comment: Why are there square brackets around the grok expression? I would've expected `["message", "..."]`, not `["message", ["..."]]`.

Comment: removing square brackets doesn't make any difference in working of logstash